# How to create static array of matrix

Tags: c, arrays, static

I have a problem with C.

I should create a static array `tmp` of 4 elements and, for all cells of this array I should store an 2x2 matrix.

Can I do this without pointers?

I tried with `int[2][2] tmp[4]` but I had a compilation error.

Comment: int[4][2][2] should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can I do this without pointers?*

You at least can avoid to explicit define pointers, by doing it like this:

1. Define the 2D `int` matrix type:

   ```
   typedef int M[2][2];
   ```
2. Define the 1D array type of the latter:

   ```
   typedef M A[4];
   ```

An example using those types could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MATRIX_ROWS (2)
#define MATRIX_COLUMNS (2)

typedef int M[MATRIX_ROWS][MATRIX_COLUMNS];

#define ARRAY_SIZE (4)

typedef M A[ARRAY_SIZE];

int matrix_set(M m)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; ++j)
    {
      m[i][j] = (int) ((i+1)*(j+1));
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int matrix_print(M m)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; ++j)
    {
      printf("m[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, m[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  A a;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    printf("setting a[%zu]:\n", i);
    matrix_set(a[i]);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    printf("printing a[%zu]:\n", i);
    matrix_print(a[i]);
  }
}
```

Please note that under the hood C *does* use pointers here, as this function declaration:

```
int matrix_set(M m);
```

in fact is

```
int matrix_set(int m[2][2]);
```

which is equivalent to

```
int matrix_set(int (*m)[2]);
```

So, although not obvious, `m` *is* a pointer, namely a pointer to an an array of 2 `int`, an `int(*)[2]`.

Additionally this call

```
  matrix_set(a[i]);
```

passes a variable of type `M`, which is a 2x2-array of `int`, an `int[2][2]`, which in fact is an array of 2 elements of type array of 2 `int`, of  `int[2]`.

If in C an array is passed to a function it is decayed to a pointer to the address of its 1st element.

The 1st element of an array of 2 elements of type array of 2 `int` is an array of 2 `int`. A pointer to the latter is of type `int(*)[2]`, which is exactly the pointer type the two functions `matrix_set()` and `matrix_print()` expect, as already explained above.

So an alternative, perhaps more puristic, but equivalent way to write the above example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MATRIX_ROWS (2)
#define MATRIX_COLUMNS (2)

#define ARRAY_SIZE (4)

int matrix_set(int (*m)[MATRIX_COLUMNS])
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; ++j)
    {
      m[i][j] = (int) ((i+1)*(j+1));
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int matrix_print(int (*m)[MATRIX_COLUMNS])
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; ++j)
    {
      printf("m[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, m[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[ARRAY_SIZE][MATRIX_ROWS][MATRIX_COLUMNS];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    printf("setting a[%zu]:\n", i);
    matrix_set(a[i]);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
  {
    printf("printing a[%zu]:\n", i);
    matrix_print(a[i]);
  }
}
```